# Cayenne SQLTemplate returning incorrect result

Tags: apache-cayenne

I'm pretty stump on this issue.  Please help.

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM scheduler_assignment a WHERE a.start < #bind($end)";
SQLTemplate query = new SQLTemplate(Assignment.class, sql);
query.setFetchingDataRows(true);
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("end", end);
query.setParameters(params);
ObjectContext context = BaseContext.getThreadObjectContext();
List<DataRow> rows = context.performQuery(query);
```

`end` is a Date object.  When I change `end` to its equivalent String, the query works correctly.  Does anyone know why passing in the Date object would not work for the bind directive?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First possibility: 'scheduler_assignment.start' column is not a date in the database. It could be a VARCHAR or something.

If this is not the case, you may have to pass the type of the argument in the #bind directive for Cayenne to use the right driver method. E.g.:

```
#bind($end 'TIMESTAMP')
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at my question. I verified that scheduler_assignment.start is a DATETIME datatype in MySQL database. I placed the type of argument like your example but I am still getting the wrong result. Here is the log of the executed SQL. When I run the query from MySQL Workbench, I receive one row. When I run the same query using the code above, I get zero row. `SELECT * FROM scheduler_assignment a WHERE a.start < ? [bind: 1:'2013-08-31 23:00:00.0']`

Comment: Could it be converting to a different timezone somewhere?

Comment: I found an answer you posted a while back.  This is helpful.  I've switched the type to TIMESTAMP and it is working perfectly.